# What is the expected number of times a 6 appears when a fair die is rolled 10 times?

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-probability, expected-value

I think I have a working solution to this problem. Here's how I would solve it:

You look at a 6 appearing as a success and everything else as a failure. From here you can use the definition of expectation with the binomial probability function to get something like

(**0** $\times$ *P*(exactly zero 6's)) + (**1** $\times$ *P*(exactly one 6)) + ... + (**10** $\times$ *P*(exactly ten 6's))

to solve the probability portions you use the binomial probability function.

Is this solution a valid way to solve the problem? Is there a better way to solve it? Because this method looks way too time consuming.

Comment: Hint: what is the expected value of one die roll? (Where rolling a $6$ is a $1$ and everything else a $0$).

Answer (score 2):

As you suggest, use the binomial distribution. Note that the expected value ($X$ is the number of successes in $n$ trials, $p$ is the probability of success in any trial) is given by

$E(X)=np=10*\frac{1}{6}$.

The derivation of the formula for the expectation as given is not too hard and should be in your textbook.

Comment: Or rather, DO NOT use the binomial distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming independence, you can do it easier:

Denote by $X_i$ the event "6 occured in roll i", and then:

$$E(X)=\sum_{i=1}^{10} E(X_i)=10E(X_1)=10*\frac16=\frac{10}6=1\frac23$$

EDIT: As noted below, you don't even need to assume independence.

Comment: @Listing You right. I must be confused with variance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As the question asks to find the expected no. of times 6 appears for 10 rolls. So it concerns is the no. of times to be the random variable for this case.
Thus writing the pdf taking the #times as the r.v. would be:

$f[n]=(1/6)^n * (5/6)^(10-n) * 10!/n!(10-n)!$

Thus writing the expectation (sum)n.f[n],

E[x]=(Sum)n*f[n]

Thus the no. of times is E[x].